# Read specific line from TextFile

Tags: delphi, pascal

Assuming that I have a text file and inside it (in the middle or something) there is the following lines :

> My name : Someone
>
> My age : 17
>
> My School : Harvard

There is no specific line number for them (random) and It's not duplicated ("My name" only shows one time , My age too etc ...)

It's not what I'm looking for exactly but I thought it should read that specific line but it's not (It's reading the whole file) :

```
AssignFile(myFile, 'C:\Users\boss\Desktop\dude.txt');
myWord := 'My name : Someone';
Reset(myFile);

while not Eof(myFile) do
begin
  readln(myFile, myWord);
  writeln(myWord);
end;

CloseFile(myFile);
```

This is reading the whole Textfile as I stated , I was just trying to get something working to manipulate it but I couldn't .

I want to read the whole line after "My name" which means the name won't be the same everytime .

Comment: You are asking the wrong question. Really what you need is a database. With a text file you need to read the entire file and count line ends until you reach your target point. Text files are not random access on a line level.

Comment: I guess I didn't ask the question as should be but I'm pretty sure it's possible to do.

Basically I want to write the whole line If the line begins with either : "My name" , "My age" , or "My school" .

Comment: No it's not possible easily. In the comment you mention writing. No mention of that in the question. You have to rewrite the entire file. Perhaps you should spend more time working out what the problem is before asking.

Comment: I mean write the lines in console application using writeln , not writing in a text file

Answer (score 3):

If I follow what you are wanting to do, it's actually simple.

Suppose you have

```
var
  ALine,
  StartOfLineToFind,
  AValue : String;
  P : Integer;

  [...]
  StartOfLineToFind := 'My name :';
```

then in your loop do

```
    readln(myFile, ALine);
    if Pos(StartOfLineToFind, ALine) = 1 then begin  // see if the line starts with the label you're looking for
      AValue := Copy(ALine, Length(StartOfLineToFind), Length(ALine) - Length(StartOfLineToFind);  //  Copy the rest of the line after the label
      AValue := Trim(AValue);  //  remove the leading and trailing spaces
      writeln(AValue);
    end;
```

Comment: Did this answer your question or not?  If it did, please feel free to accept it.

Answer (score 3):

*Cleaning my crystal ball...*
Probably you need something like this code:

```
readln(myFile, myWord);
if Pos('My name:', myWord) = 1 then
  Writeln(myWord);
```